# JSON or XML either way I need to format a JS array from a URL

Tags: jquery, xml, arrays, json

I'm using the [JQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) and I need some help formatting data available to me. I have a url that can output data in XML or JSON:

JSON example:

```
[{"location":{"address":"Dortha Pike","city":"Emmerichburgh","created_at":"2011-05-19T00:03:20Z","id":3,"name":"Caroline Fahey DDS","state":"Illinois","updated_at":"2011-05-19T00:03:20Z","zip":"80822-2018"}}
```

XML example:

```
<locations type="array">
<location>
<address>Dortha Pike</address>
<city>Emmerichburgh</city>
<created-at type="datetime">2011-05-19T00:03:20Z</created-at>
<id type="integer">3</id>
<name>Caroline Fahey DDS</name>
<state>Illinois</state>
<updated-at type="datetime">2011-05-19T00:03:20Z</updated-at>
<zip>80822-2018</zip>
</location>
```

The function below accepts data in a JS array. **My problem is I need to take either of the above data and format it like you see var data is below:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = "Core Selectors Attributes Traversing Manipulation CSS Events Effects Ajax Utilities".split(" ");
$("#example").autocomplete(data);
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand what you're asking for. The data in the XML and JSON doesn't look anything like the data in var data = ...

Comment: I guess they want var data = "Dortha Pike Emmerichburgh 2011..." where each array element is flattened and separated by a space?

Comment: @brian exactly. I need to change the way it looks. I need to Make XML or JSON into an Array using JS. How do you do this?

Comment: Actually I meant that the data itself looks different. var data = ... looks like tags for a programmers blog and the XML and JSON looks like contact information. If I were to answer, I could only give a generality of how JSON can be used to pass arrays (similar to what Abe has shown in his answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using the autocomplete I think your using, the string seperated by spaces is only one format... you can use JSON as long as you have particular names for the variables.

```
$item =  $item . "{ \"id\": \"$id\", \"label\": \"$name\"},";
```

So in your case you have to pick a field, like name, and parse all the names into a string like:

```
   [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "label": "Caroline Fahey DDS"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "label": "Another Name"
    }
   ]
```

Can certainly help you with that, just check that string works first as it might be a different plugin.

EDIT: Provided example

the php/ajax response

```
<?php
$q = getGET("term");
if($q != "")
{
  $q = fquery_sanitize($q);
  $sql = "select ManufacturerID, ManufacturerName from sds_manufacturer ". 
         " where ManufacturerName LIKE '%$q%' ".
         " order by ManufacturerName";
  $result = fquery_db($sql);
  $item= "";
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $id = $row["ManufacturerID"];
    $name = $row["ManufacturerName"];
    $item =  $item . "{ \"id\": \"$id\", \"label\": \"$name\"},";
  }
  echo "["; 
  echo trim($item, ",");
  echo "]";
}

?>
```

The autocomplete

```
$('.manufacturer-form .name').autocomplete({
          source: "/portal/inc/prod_manage/man-list-json.php",
            minLength: 3,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                     manufacturer_select(ui.item.id);
          }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the above JSON format. But it would be interesting to see how you were able to parse that. I would accept that as the correct answer.

Comment: to test it just do var data = <my string above>, It should work automatically. I'll edit my answer and provde an example.

Comment: Found a syntax error in the JSON string, ran it through a validator and changed to the fixed JSON string.